# Accessing and comparing data in jQuery loop

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table on my page which is dynamically built and contains editable data fields.  The table looks something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="identifier">1</td>
    <td class="c1"><input type="number" data-id="123" value="123" /></td>
    <td class="c2"><input type="number" data-id="456" value="456" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="identifier">2</td>
    <td class="c1"><input type="number" data-id="321" value="321" /></td>
    <td class="c2"><input type="number" data-id="654" value="654" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am using a jQuery .each() loop over all the tr elements, and trying to compare the values of each input to the data=id (the data-id is set at the server as equal to the initial value of the box) so I can save changed values when the user clicks a button.

My function looks something like this:

```
$('tr').each(function (index, element) {
    var idToSave = $(element).children('.identifier').first().text();
    var toSave = false;
    var $cone = $(element).children('td.pup input[type=number]').first();
    var $ctwo = $(element).children('td.van input[type=number]').first();

    var x = $cone.text();
    alert('Text: ' + x);
    var y = $cone.val();
    alert('Val: ' + y);
    var z = $cone.data("id");
    alert('Data: ' + z);
    
    if ($cone.text() != $cone.data("id")) {
        toSave = true;
    }

    if (toSave) {
        //Do an ajax call to the save method, passing in values
    }
});
```

When I run my jQuery each() function, I see the identifier correctly (verified by alerts I've since removed) but the variables x, y, and z all come back as undefined.  I have confirmed that the variable names are unique within my page (they are NOT x,y,z in my actual page, just this simplified version) and I have experimented with many versions of the code, including using .attr("data-id") and .dataset.id to pull the data off of my input.  I feel like I'm missing something simple and obvious.

Cany anyone give any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems here seems:

- `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/children/))
  *this was causing the `undefined` values, since starting from `tr` you can only search for direct children (I.E. some `td`) but not `td` children as `input`.*
- Using `.data('id')` returns type number the first time
  (because it parse as a number from `data-id="123"`)
- missing `.pup` and `.van` classes in td (`td.pup`, `td.van` selectors are missing; there are no `td` with this classes, so no inputs will be found)

---

##### Solution

- Update your `.children(selector)` method with `.find(selector)` to find deep nested elements
- Concat `''` to your `.data('id')` to make it a string and to check against your input value.
- Update your toBeSaved value by checking all the conditions you need

In the following example i used a listener for `input.keyup()` to run the `.each()` function on each input change

```js
// I'm setting up a keyup listener to run our .each() every time some input get a keyup event
$('input').keyup(function() {
  console.clear()
  // I'm using 'tbody tr' as selector to exlude the first 'tr' (the header tr aka 'thead tr') 
  $('tbody tr').each(function(index, element) {

    // Use .find() to search for children element

    // this is because .children() method differs from .find() 
    // in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree 
    var idToSave = $(element).find('.identifier').first().text();
    var c1 = $(element).find('td.c1 input[type=number]').first();
    var c2 = $(element).find('td.c2 input[type=number]').first();

    // Check if some value needs to be saved (using .attr() to get 'data-id' value)
    var toSave = c1.val() !== c1.data("id") + '' || c2.val() !== c2.data('id') + '';

    if (toSave) {
      // Optionally build queryString params for your fetch
      /// Note that to do this, i added 'name' attribute in our input
      const rowSerialized = $(element).find('input').filter(function(el) {

        // Including only fields with updated value

        const res = ($(this).data('id') + '') !== $(this).val();
        // Note that .data() will return number the first time

        return res;
      }).serialize();

      // Optionally build a diff object from the serialized string
      const rowDiffsObject = parseSerializedRow(rowSerialized)

      console.log("Saving Row With Id: ", idToSave, "\nDiff Object: ", rowDiffsObject);

      // Just for this example i'm faking save by updating the data-id
      c1.data('id', c1.val());
      c2.data('id', c2.val());
    }
  });
})

// just convert from serialized string
// to diffs object
function parseSerializedRow(rowSerialized) {
  let rowDiffs = {}
  rowSerialized.split('&').forEach((field) => {
    const split = field.split('=');
    const fieldName = split[0];
    const fieldValue = split[1];
    rowDiffs[fieldName] = fieldValue;
  });
  return rowDiffs;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Data 1</th>
      <th>Data 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="identifier">1</td>
      <td class="c1"><input type="number" name="data1" data-id="123" value="123" /></td>
      <td class="c2"><input type="number" name="data2" data-id="456" value="456" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="identifier">2</td>
      <td class="c1"><input type="number" name="data1" data-id="321" value="321" /></td>
      <td class="c2"><input type="number" name="data2" data-id="654" value="654" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>Update the values to see when some row needs to update</p>
```

*This way you will be able to perform a save each time one of your lines is updated.*

Please note that using .data() to get the initial value (`data-id="123"`) will return a number instead of string.  This is because i concat `+''` every time i check the .data('id')

Comment: D'oh.  Indeed, that was the crux of the issue - children() only looking a single level down.  The 'pup' and 'van' classes were an oversight where I forgot to switch the real things from my actual code to match the simplified.  In my defense, I'd been hammering at the problem for over 4 hours and it was the middle of the night.

Comment: I updated the post using again .data() instead of .attr() (with the same result). 
Note that it will return a number because the parsing of `data-id="123"`  became `123` and not `'123'` that's why i concat `''` before comparing with `.val()`.     
P.S. The middle of the night has its pros and cons :) And i'm speaking as night big fan